# SSH Problems with Ansible with Packer on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, packer

I am trying to build a ami with packer and ansible and I keep running into a SSH error,

```
    amazon-ebs.bio-base: fatal: [default]: UNREACHABLE! => {
    amazon-ebs.bio-base:     "changed": false,
    amazon-ebs.bio-base:     "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022\r\nBad owner or permissions on /home/myuser/.ssh/config",
    amazon-ebs.bio-base:     "unreachable": true
    amazon-ebs.bio-base: }
```

My `hcl` file consists of,

```
packer {
  required_plugins {
    amazon = {
      version = ">= 1.2.5"
      source  = "github.com/hashicorp/amazon"
    }
  }
}

variables {
  instance_role = "packer_ssm_agent"
}

source "amazon-ebs" "bio-base" {
  ami_name      = "bio-base"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  region        = "us-east-1"
  source_ami_filter {
    filters = {
      name                = "ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-jammy-22.04-amd64-server-*"
      root-device-type    = "ebs"
      virtualization-type = "hvm"
    }
    most_recent = true
    owners      = ["099720109477"]
  }
  communicator         = "ssh"
  ssh_username         = "ubuntu"
  ssh_interface        = "session_manager"
  iam_instance_profile = var.instance_role
}

build {
  sources = ["source.amazon-ebs.bio-base"]

  provisioner "ansible" {
    playbook_file           = "./ansible/playbook.yml"
    extra_arguments         = ["-vvvv"]
    use_proxy               = false
    inventory_file_template = "{{ .HostAlias }} ansible_host={{ .ID }} ansible_user={{ .User }} ansible_ssh_common_args='-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ProxyCommand=\"sh -c \\\"aws ssm start-session --target %h --document-name AWS-StartSSHSession --parameters portNumber=%p\\\"\"'\n"
    ansible_env_vars        = ["PACKER_BUILD_NAME={{ build_name }}"]

  }

}
```

I passed verbose logging to ansible so here is the output of those logs,

```
==> amazon-ebs.bio-base: Waiting for SSH to become available...
    amazon-ebs.bio-base: Starting portForwarding session "Administrator-08g5hy56c7efg2d8e".
    amazon-ebs.bio-base: Starting session with SessionId: Administrator-08g5hy56c7efg2d8e
    amazon-ebs.bio-base: Port 8944 opened for sessionId Administrator-08g5hy56c7efg2d8e.
    amazon-ebs.bio-base: Waiting for connections...
    amazon-ebs.bio-base: Connection accepted for session [Administrator-08g5hy56c7efg2d8e]
==> amazon-ebs.bio-base: Connected to SSH!
==> amazon-ebs.bio-base: Provisioning with Ansible...
    amazon-ebs.bio-base: Not using Proxy adapter for Ansible run:
    amazon-ebs.bio-base:        Using ssh keys from Packer communicator...
==> amazon-ebs.bio-base: Executing Ansible: ansible-playbook -e packer_build_name="bio-base" -e packer_builder_type=amazon-ebs --ssh-extra-args '-o IdentitiesOnly=yes' -vvvv -e ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/tmp/ansible-key4136004760 -i /tmp/packer-provisioner-ansible1791148040 /home/myuser/projects/org/terraform-development-ami/ansible/playbook.yml
    amazon-ebs.bio-base: ansible-playbook [core 2.15.1]
    amazon-ebs.bio-base:   config file = None
    amazon-ebs.bio-base:   configured module search path = ['/home/myuser/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
    amazon-ebs.bio-base:   ansible python module location = /home/myuser/projects/org/terraform-development-ami/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible
    amazon-ebs.bio-base:   ansible collection location = /home/myuser/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
    amazon-ebs.bio-base:   executable location = /home/myuser/projects/org/terraform-development-ami/.venv/bin/ansible-playbook
    amazon-ebs.bio-base:   python version = 3.9.16 (main, May  4 2023, 21:16:03) [GCC 11.3.0] (/home/myuser/projects/org/terraform-development-ami/.venv/bin/python)
    amazon-ebs.bio-base:   jinja version = 3.1.2
    amazon-ebs.bio-base:   libyaml = True
    amazon-ebs.bio-base: No config file found; using defaults
    amazon-ebs.bio-base: setting up inventory plugins
    amazon-ebs.bio-base: Loading collection ansible.builtin from
    amazon-ebs.bio-base: host_list declined parsing /tmp/packer-provisioner-ansible1791148040 as it did not pass its verify_file() method
    amazon-ebs.bio-base: script declined parsing /tmp/packer-provisioner-ansible1791148040 as it did not pass its verify_file() method
    amazon-ebs.bio-base: auto declined parsing /tmp/packer-provisioner-ansible1791148040 as it did not pass its verify_file() method
    amazon-ebs.bio-base: Parsed /tmp/packer-provisioner-ansible1791148040 inventory source with ini plugin
    amazon-ebs.bio-base: Loading callback plugin default of type stdout, v2.0 from /home/myuser/projects/org/terraform-development-ami/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/default.py
    amazon-ebs.bio-base: Skipping callback 'default', as we already have a stdout callback.
    amazon-ebs.bio-base: Skipping callback 'minimal', as we already have a stdout callback.
    amazon-ebs.bio-base: Skipping callback 'oneline', as we already have a stdout callback.
    amazon-ebs.bio-base:
    amazon-ebs.bio-base: PLAYBOOK: playbook.yml *********************************************************
    amazon-ebs.bio-base: Positional arguments: /home/myuser/projects/org/terraform-development-ami/ansible/playbook.yml
    amazon-ebs.bio-base: verbosity: 4
    amazon-ebs.bio-base: connection: smart
    amazon-ebs.bio-base: timeout: 10
    amazon-ebs.bio-base: ssh_extra_args: '-o IdentitiesOnly=yes'
    amazon-ebs.bio-base: become_method: sudo
    amazon-ebs.bio-base: tags: ('all',)
    amazon-ebs.bio-base: inventory: ('/tmp/packer-provisioner-ansible1791148040',)
    amazon-ebs.bio-base: extra_vars: ('packer_build_name="bio-base"', 'packer_builder_type=amazon-ebs', 'ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/tmp/ansible-key4136004760')
    amazon-ebs.bio-base: forks: 5
    amazon-ebs.bio-base: 1 plays in /home/myuser/projects/org/terraform-development-ami/ansible/playbook.yml
    amazon-ebs.bio-base:
    amazon-ebs.bio-base: PLAY [all] *********************************************************************
    amazon-ebs.bio-base:
    amazon-ebs.bio-base: TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
    amazon-ebs.bio-base: task path: /home/myuser/projects/org/terraform-development-ami/ansible/playbook.yml:2
    amazon-ebs.bio-base: <i-0a5fe8ab55fa3829b> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: ubuntu
    amazon-ebs.bio-base: <i-0a5fe8ab55fa3829b> SSH: EXEC ssh -vvv -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'IdentityFile="/tmp/ansible-key4136004760"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="ubuntu"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'ProxyCommand=sh -c "aws ssm start-session --target %h --document-name AWS-StartSSHSession --parameters portNumber=%p"' '-o IdentitiesOnly=yes' -o 'ControlPath="/home/myuser/.ansible/cp/c629d62b6f"' i-0a5fe8ab55fa3829b '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~ubuntu && sleep 0'"'"''
    amazon-ebs.bio-base: <i-0a5fe8ab55fa3829b> (255, b'', b'OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022\r\nBad owner or permissions on /home/myuser/.ssh/config\r\n')
    amazon-ebs.bio-base: fatal: [default]: UNREACHABLE! => {
    amazon-ebs.bio-base:     "changed": false,
    amazon-ebs.bio-base:     "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022\r\nBad owner or permissions on /home/myuser/.ssh/config",
    amazon-ebs.bio-base:     "unreachable": true
    amazon-ebs.bio-base: }
    amazon-ebs.bio-base:
    amazon-ebs.bio-base: PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
    amazon-ebs.bio-base: default                    : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

I am not sure why it's looking in `/home/myuser/.ssh/config`?

Comment: You may want to also enable Packer verbose logging. Also, is there a reason not to fix the permissions issue described in the error message?

Comment: @MattSchuchard - I am storing ssh keys in `/home/myuser/.ssh/config` these are not related to packer/ansible; so I am not sure why ansible is lookin there, from the logs shouldn't it be looking `ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/tmp/ansible-key4136004760`